# Facing SpringBoot Security module login error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am creating spring boot basic application with login feature.

My login feature is not working and generating below debug log.

```
2019-09-26 14:50:01.262 DEBUG 3720 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6deb15fd
2019-09-26 14:50:01.277 DEBUG 3720 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6deb15fd
```

Below is my controller class code.

```
package com.sourabh.app.controller;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;    
import com.sourabh.app.repository.SpringJava4sDAO;
import com.sourabh.model.Customer;

@RestController
public class MainAppController {

    @Autowired
    public SpringJava4sDAO dao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome to Sring boot application";
    }

        @RequestMapping("/userlogin")
        public String userValidation() {
            return "User: Successfully logged in!";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/adminlogin")
        public String adminValidation() {
            return "Admin: Successfully logged in!";
        }
}
```

Below is my SpringSecurityConfig class code

```
package com.sourabh.app.configs;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Authentication : set user/password details and mention the role
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance())
            .withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER")
            .and()
            .withUser("admin").password("pass").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    // Authorization : mention which role can access which URL
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/userlogin").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/adminlogin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();
    }
}
```

Added dependency is pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Boot Driver Class code

```
package com.sourabh.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApp.class, args);

    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MainApp.class);
    }
}
```

Am i missing anything, or made any mistake?

Note:- dao and model are not included in question as they are not part of login process. **Login pop-up is coming but its authorizing use**r.

Comment: ` .antMatchers("/userlogin").hasRole("USER"),` login should permitAll?

Comment: @Jerry06 sorry what? I am new with spring and still learning. can you please elaborate?

Comment: @SSP what Jerry meant is that you are protecting your login endpoint. So when anybody tries to access `/userlogin` or `/adminlogin` Spring actually checks if they are logged in. It can be solved by replacing `hasRole(ROLE)` with `permitAll()`. That way anybody can access the login endpoints

Comment: changed antMatchers("/userlogin").hasRole("USER") to antMatchers("/userlogin").permitAll() for both. still not working.

Comment: @SSP well, what exactly is not working and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `@Configuration`. your configuration class should be annotated as given below.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
...
}
```

Comment: @SSP I didn't notice `.httpBasic()` in your configuration so suggested `.formLogin()`. Because of not noticing `.httpBasic()` i completely concentrated on authentication filter. Deleted previous answer and added new answer.

Comment: No. I followed https://www.java4s.com/spring-boot-tutorials/spring-boot-spring-security-restful-web-service-with-basic-authentication/ this. I think there must be some other error. So now i am using spring standard guide.